# How to find fulfillment_summary in SQLite. How to find order % of total orders

Tags: sql, orders, fulfillment, warehouse

This is my QUERY in SQLite.
Currently following the Google Data Analytics Certificate.

```
SELECT
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    Warehouse.state || ': ' || Warehouse.warehouse_alias AS warehouse_name,
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*)
        FROM Warehouse_Orders Orders)
    AS total_orders,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders Orders) <= 0.20
        THEN 'Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders'
        WHEN COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders Orders) > 0.20
        AND COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders Orders) <= 0.60
        THEN 'Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders'
        ELSE 'Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders'
        END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM Warehouse_Stats Warehouse
LEFT JOIN Warehouse_Orders Orders
ON Warehouse.warehouse_id = Orders.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    warehouse_name
HAVING
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) >1
```

I realise it is a problem with my CASE

- The Orders.order_id is fine as the COUNT returns the number of orders per warehouse.
  -Yet the total is not working "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders Orders"

How do I find the total?

I've tried, to take my SQL query apart and try different methods but I'm struggling to return the total.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid running the same query multiple times. For more complex analysis you often need to think in steps: get this result set and query that for the next step. You can do this using a derived table.

Also note you should convert integers to decimal numbers before devision and comparison to a another decimal. Does it work for you?

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN 
        (CAST(total_orders as REAL)/CAST(number_of_orders as REAL)) <= 0.2
        THEN 'Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders'
        WHEN 
        (CAST(total_orders as REAL)/CAST(number_of_orders as REAL)) BETWEEN 0.2 and 0.6
        THEN 'Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders'
        ELSE 'Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders'
    END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        Warehouse.warehouse_id,
        Warehouse.state || ': ' || Warehouse.warehouse_alias AS warehouse_name,
        COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders Orders) AS total_orders
    FROM Warehouse_Stats Warehouse
    LEFT JOIN Warehouse_Orders Orders ON Warehouse.warehouse_id = Orders.warehouse_id
    GROUP BY Warehouse.warehouse_id, warehouse_name
    HAVING COUNT(Orders.order_id) >1
) totals
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried to run your query and it made all values be retrieved as over 60%. The solution to this after a lot of searching was for me to times each count in the case statement by 1.0. This is my updated version below :).                                                                                                                *** CASE
        WHEN 1.0 * COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders Orders) <= 0.20 **** and so on

Comment: Great! Yeah, conversions and operations usually need a little tuning. Please update the query in the answer for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED VERSION:

So after a lot of searching on the Web, I realised that while using SQLite you have to convert numbers before looking to make percentages out of them.

This is the end result of the query that worked for me.

```
SELECT
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    Warehouse.state || ': ' || Warehouse.warehouse_alias AS warehouse_name,
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*)
        FROM Warehouse_Orders Orders)
    AS total_orders,
    CASE
        WHEN 1.0 * COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders) <= 0.20
        THEN 'Fulfilled 0-20% of Orders'
        WHEN 1.0 * COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders) > 0.20
        AND 1.0 * COUNT(Orders.order_id)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Warehouse_Orders) <= 0.60
        THEN 'Fulfilled 21-60% of Orders'
        ELSE 'Fulfilled more than 60% of Orders'
        END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM Warehouse_Stats Warehouse
LEFT JOIN Warehouse_Orders Orders
ON Warehouse.warehouse_id = Orders.warehouse_id
GROUP BY
    Warehouse.warehouse_id,
    warehouse_name
HAVING
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) >1
```

As you can see I input 1.0 * ... For each COUNT of the individual orders.
Which ended up making the percentages work.